Create new set of columns for each key and value combination
I have a table as below



ID
Ver
key
val




101
1
Resunit
mm


101
1
ResPower
500


101
1
ResWeight
520


101
2
Winunit
mm


101
2
WinPower
50


101
2
WinWeight
20


102
1
capunit
km


102
1
capPower
200


102
1
capWeight
20



SQL Fiddle to create the above table
Required output



ID
REV
key1
val1
key2
val2
key3
val3




101
1
Resunit
mm
ResPower
500
ResWeight
520


101
2
Winunit
mm
WinPower
50
WinWeight
20


102
1
capunit
km
capPower
200
capWeight
20



I have tried doing pivot using below sql. But here the problem is the keys for each id & ver combination are different and the users want to see the output in the above format only. This may not be solved using regular pivot. Is there an way to achieve it? please suggest
select *
from 
(
  select *
  from yt 
) src
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for keys in ([Resunit], [ResPower], [ResWeight])
) piv;

DB<>Fiddle

Sorry, the tagged question didn't answer my scenarios. I don't want to convert columns to rows or multi pivot. This is kind of having new set of columns for each key and value

If those don't answer, then I'm confident that the new dupe target I've added does.
